# Function to return digits from a string, if length >= 4

Tags: javascript, regex

This function is retrieving the last numbers of a string:

```
function getLastNumberOfString(str){
  var allNumbers = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ' ').trim().split(/\s+/);
  return parseInt(allNumbers[allNumbers.length - 1], 10);
}
```

I want it to retrieve the last numbers of a string, if it contains at least 4 digits.

For example:

```
"1234-string-text/8177-1-3-tools-for-knowledge.html"
```

Is returning:

```
3
```

I'd like it to return:

```
8177
```

Comment: Does the string always have that format: `/` and then the four numbers you want?

Comment: No, it maybe different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match last set of numbers containing at least 4 digits use:

```bash
\d{4,}(?!.+\d{4})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ewgVTe/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\d{4,}`: Match 4 or more digits
- `(?!.+\d{4})`: Negative Lookahead to assert that there is no other occurrence of 4 digit numbers ahead

**Code:**

```js
function getLastNumberOfString(str){
  var m = str.match(/\d{4,}(?!.+\d{4})/);
  return (m ? parseInt(m[0]) : NaN);
}

console.log(getLastNumberOfString("1234-string-text/8177-1-3-tools-for-knowledge.html"));

console.log(getLastNumberOfString("tools-for-knowledge.html"));
```